# Arduino GPIB control

Tags: usb

I want to control a scientific instrument with an Arduino through GPIB. I have a USB-GPIB adapter, so I would want to do it through the USB. There are tutorials on the Internet on how to connect Arduino to a GPIB instrument through pins, but I did not fid any explanation of how to do it though USB. Is there a software package I can use?

Comment: an arduino can interface to something simple like a USB keyboard or mouse ... it may have problems with interfacing GPIB through the USB ... you would be better off using something like a Raspberry Pi ... it uses Linux as an operating system ... it has the necessary hardware to make use of the USB-GPIB adapter .... the necessary software may also be available .... google `linux gpib instrument` to see if there is any scientific software that you could use

Comment: Is there a reason, why you want to use the USB-GPIB adapter? When there are tutorials on how to directly interface GPIB, why do you want to involve the USB interface? USB is a rather complex interface and the possible capabilities of Arduinos (depending on which version you use) regarding USB are limited.